# SocketIO Nodejs and PHP , how to make it work?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express, xampp

I have this simple chat app, that is supposed to show received messages in real time without refreshing.

I am running xampp on port 80.

This I have included on index.php

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:80/nodePHP-master\js\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="js/nodeClient.js"></script>
```

**nodeClient.js** is

```
    var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:80' );

    $( "#messageForm" ).submit( function() {
    var nameVal = $( "#nameInput" ).val();
    var msg = $( "#messageInput" ).val();

    socket.emit( 'message', { name: nameVal, message: msg } );

    // Ajax call for saving datas
    $.ajax({
    url: "./ajax/insertNewMessage.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { name: nameVal, message: msg },
    success: function(data) {

    }
    });

    return false;
     });

    socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
    var actualContent = $( "#messages" ).html();
    var newMsgContent = '<li> <strong>' + data.name + '</strong> : ' +        data.message + '</li>';
   var content = newMsgContent + actualContent;

   $( "#messages" ).html( content );
   });
```

And **nodeServer.js** is

```
    var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
    var express = require( 'express' );
    var http = require( 'http' );

    var app = express();
    var server = http.createServer( app );

    var io = socket.listen( server );

    io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
    console.log( "New client !" );

    client.on( 'message', function( data ) {
    console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message );

    //client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message:  data.message } );
    io.sockets.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message }   );
    });
    });

    server.listen( 80 );
```

But I keep getting this error message in console :

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: you can not use both php & node servers on the same port, try to put node server on another port, 8000 for example and change the client to use that port

Comment: How about on my index page ? Should I put there localhost:8000 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it.

Did not know that I had to start nodeServer.js

Accessed its location via cmd, and endered **node nodeServer.js**