# Trying to use php site with socket.io chat application but it downloads php code instead

Tags: php, websocket, server, socket.io

I have created a chat application using the walk through on socket.io

I have added further content to the application, including database info, which meant I had to change the index.html to current session.php.

Now when I try and run the application, it just downloads a document with all the code for the page, and it does not run.

I have changed all the code to current session.php where necessary.

If I change the file name back to current session.html and change the relevant code, it then works fine....

I really need to have database info on the page, which is why it needs to be current session.php

Does anyone know why it does this? Is there a work around?

Code for index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.get('/currentsession', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Staff/html/current session.php');
});

app.get('/question', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Student/Question.php');
});

io.emit('some event', { for: 'everyone' });

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.broadcast.emit('hi');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

var nsp = io.of('/currentsession');
nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('/currentsession');
});

var nsp = io.of('/question');
nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('/question');
});

var nsp = io.of('/currentsession');
nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

var nsp = io.of('/currentsession');
nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('go-to-page', function(data){
io.of('/question').emit('go-to-page', { href: "//selene.hud.ac.uk/u1555602"});
  });
});

http.listen(4000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:4000');
});
```

code for current session.php

```
<?php include('server.php') ?> 
<?php 


    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
        header('location: sign in.php');
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Wireless Response System</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head>


<div class="heading">
<div class="php">
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) :
$query = ("SELECT discipline FROM user WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$resultset = $conn->query($query);
while ($user = $resultset->fetch()) {
echo '<h1> Discipline:'; echo $user["discipline"]; '</h1>'; }
endif
?>
</div>
<nav> 
<ul>

    <form action="">
      <button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
  var socket = io('/currentsession');
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('go-to-page', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
  socket.on('go-to-page', function (data) {
    window.location.replace(data.href);
  });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Does your webserver support php? If it does not it will see the php files as plain text files and just download them

Comment: @Marvin Yes, my server does support php.

Comment: Sounds to me that you're trying to run the file directly. Try WAMP or MAMP to run PHP.

Comment: @FelixMichaelCervin have ran it on WAMP and a real time server too

Comment: Are you accessing the file via "localhost"?

Comment: @FelixMichaelCervin Yes i am, and i have also accessed it with a proper URL as i had uploaded it to a server

Comment: Then I would advise providing some code to your question, since us (readers) have no idea to what your code looks like

Comment: @FelixMichaelCervin I have updated the question with code

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Staff/html/current session.php');
> ```

You have written an HTTP server using Node.js.

For some HTTP requests, your server will respond by reading the source code of a PHP file and then sending it to the browser.

You need to **run the PHP program** and send its output, not the source code.

Typically you would do this by using a server optimised for running PHP (such as Apache HTTPD) and having the browser make the request to that server and not the one created using Node.js.

Comment: i understand about using a server optimised for running PHP, however i do not know about "having the browser make the request to that server and not the one created using Node.js."

Comment: can you please explain this step further?

Comment: You change the URL you type into the browser so it is the URL to a PHP page hosted on Apache and not to the your Node.js server

Comment: I have just tried this. it now loads the php file, however the socket.io part does not link up with clients..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124712/socketio-nodejs-and-php-how-to-make-it-work